# How to drop same rows in 3 pandas objects?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to drop same rows in 2 pandas dataframes (`df_train` and `df_train`) and 1 pandas series (`y_train`). All of them have the same number of rows.

This is my current code:

```
indices = df_train[(df_train.col1!=0) | (df_train.col2!=10)].index

df_train = df_train.drop(indices)
X_train = X_train.drop(indices)
y_train = y_train.drop(indices)
```

It works well for `df_train` and `X_train`, but fails for `y_train` saying that indices cannot be found in `y_train` (`KeyError`).

Comment: adding try except protection

Comment: @BENY: I need to drop all rows that correspond to `indices`, so that all 3 objects have same number of rows at the end. If I use try-except, `y_train` will have more rows than other two objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different indices, but because same number of rows is possible change logic - get rows by conditions with inverting to numpy array for `X_train, y_train`:

```
m = (df_train.col1==0) & (df_train.col2==10)

df_train = df_train[m]
X_train = X_train[m.to_numpy()]
y_train = y_train[m.to_numpy()]
```

Or invert mask:

```
m = (df_train.col1!=0) | (df_train.col2!=10)

df_train = df_train[~m]
X_train = X_train[~m.to_numpy()]
y_train = y_train[~m.to_numpy()]
```

Your solution working if same indices in all 3 pandas objects:

```
df_train = df_train.reset_index(drop=True)
X_train = X_train.reset_index(drop=True)
y_train = y_train.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to define a boolean mask and apply it:

```py
# note the mask is inverted (spotted this after checking @jezrael's answer)
mask = ~((df_train.col1!=0) | (df_train.col2!=10))


df_train = df_train.loc[mask]
X_train = X_train.loc[mask]
y_train = y_train.loc[mask]
```